# debug and inspect $_POST

Tags: php

Lets say that i have 2 pages: index.php and service.php

index.php sends an http-post to service.php, containing a datestamp once every 5th minute.

How would i debug the post variables on service.php? Obviously i cant just do a

```
if(isset($_POST['key'])) { 
    var_dump($_POST['key']); 
}
```

since it wont exist when i enter the page.

In ASP.NET i would just create a breakpoint, but how would i inspect the posted data in php?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Save the status of the `$_POST` array to a file using `var_export` (with the current `time()` to avoid overwrites), and inspect the file later.

```
file_put_contents( 'debug' . time() . '.log', var_export( $_POST, true));
```

Comment: I didnt explain myself very well but it looks like you understood  my question :) Where is this file saved?

Comment: the file will be saved in the same directory as your script is in.

Answer (score 5):

You can output the values of post using `var_dump` or `print_r`, I am not following why you say that you "can't"

There are, indeed, several ways to debug post data:

- [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) - intercept and change form post data
- [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) - debug http requests
- You can also use Firebug, which is an excellent general-purpose debugging tool. With the "Net" panel, one could debug post data sent and the server's output:

  [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug) - General-purpose development tool.
- Firebug has extensions itself; there is one called [FirePHP](http://www.firephp.org/) which allows you to trace debug data to the Firebug console. I have personally not had much luck setting FirePHP up, but I've not put forward a serious attempt, either.
- You can also use built-in tools: in Chrome (<kbd>F12</kbd>)or in Firefox (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>)
- Log debug data to the error log using the `error_log` command:

  error_log("\n".serialize($_POST), 3, "/var/tmp/my-errors.log");

**Documentation**

PHP's var_dump - http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

PHP's print_r - http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

PHP's error_log - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Article discussing Firebug with FirePHP - http://sixrevisions.com/web-development/how-to-debug-php-using-firefox-with-firephp/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [print_r](http://php.net/print_r) to inspect data in a human-readable way.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're responding to an internal request made by another PHP script on the server, you have several options: [log it to `syslog`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.syslog.php), log it to your own logfile or a database, or send a mail somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, right now im saving it to a database. But the log sounds like a better options while debugging

Answer (score 0):

for php (applicable to many IDE, you will need to configure your specific IDE however) one can use [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) to set breakpoints and [inspect](http://www.fieg.nl/debugging-php-with-eclipse-and-xdebug) your variables